# Does the word "Brahman" occur in the Rig Veda to denote the impersonal supreme principle?

Tags: rig-veda, brahman

Does the word "Brahman" occur in the Rig Veda to denote the impersonal supreme principle?
If not, which scripture does it occur in first?

Comment: Provide some explanation to your question.

Answer (score 7):

## In which scripture the word Brahman as  impersonal supreme Principle does  occur  first?

The word Brahman as impersonal supreme Principle is mentioned in Vedas .The word  Brahman occured in [**Shukla Yajurveda Samhita**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/yajurveda/v3.18) Chapter 32- Mantra 1. This sukta is dedicated to "Brahma-Swayambhu". ब्रह्म स्वयम्भु.

> तदेवाग्निस्तदादित्यस्तद्वायुस्तदु चन्द्रमा :| 
> तदेव शुक्रं तद्
>   **ब्रह्म** ता आप: स प्रजापति: ||1||
>
> All pervading **Paramatma** himself is self-born prajapati ,his luster
>   is like Agni and Surya , he is Aditya , all prevesive Vayu , Blissful
>   Moon , bright Shukra ,pure , excellent , excellent guide **Brahman** ,
>   water which is all inclusive and sustainer of all the living beings.

---

The word Brahman as impersonal supreme Principle  is also mentioned in
[**Atharva Veda**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v3.86)-  Kanda 10 Sukta 7 -Mantra 11,17,24 - SarvaaDharVarnan sukta (सर्वाधारवर्णन सुक्त) - a sukta for the principle who is base of all this universe

> यत्र लोकाच्श्र कोशांच्श्रापो **ब्रह्म** जना विदु: |
>  असच्च यत्र
>   सच्चान्त: स्कम्भं तं ब्रुहि  कतम: स्विदेव स : |
>  यत्र तप: पराक्रम्य
>   व्रतं धारयत्युत्तरम् |
>  ऋतं च यत्र श्रद्धा चापो **ब्रह्म** समाहिता:
>   स्कम्भं तं ब्रुहि कतम कतम: स्विदेव स :   || AV 10.7.11||
>
> Tell us that Skambha where people by performing Tapas , Vratas they
>   become excellence · fame · honored and where Rita ,Shradha and Apa
>   ,**Brahman** is inclusive.

---

> ये पुरुषे **ब्रह्म** विदुस्ते विदु: परमेष्ठिनं यच्श्र वेद प्रजापतिम् |
>   जेष्ठं ये ब्राह्मणं विदुस्ते स्कम्भमनुसंविदु: || AV 10.7.17||
>
> Those who knows the Brahman ,knows "Parameshti" ,those who know
>   Parameshti ,Prajapati and elderly "brahman" , they knows the "Skambha"

And also in Mantra 24

> यत्र देवा ब्रह्मविदो ब्रह्म जेष्ठमुपासते |
>  यो वै तान् विद्यात्
>   प्रत्यक्षं स ब्रह्मा वेदिता स्यात् || [**AV 10.7.24**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/atharveda/v3.87)||
>
> Where "Brahmavetta" worship Supreme Brahman or the one who Knows him
>   Verily , the knower can be Brahman.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are actually many mantras in rig veda in which brahman appears here is one of them

> यो विश्वस्य जगतः पराणतस पतिर्यो बरह्मणे परथमो गा अविन्दत |  इन्द्रो यो
>   दस्यून्रधरानवातिरन म... || (RigVeda 1.101.5)
>
> He who is Lord of all the world that moves and breathes, who for the
>   Brahman first before all found the Cows; Indra who cast the Dasyus
>   down beneath his feet,—him girt by Maruts we invoke to be our Friend.

Many gods are also also equated with purusha and brahman.