# Is there any mention of Brahman in the Samhitas of any of the 4 Vedas?

Tags: vedas, brahman

Is there any mention of Brahman in the *Samhitas* of any of the 4 Vedas?

Brahman is elaborately described in the Aranyakas and Upanishads of the Vedas, but what about the Samhitas?

Comment: The Answer is already present - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26881

Answer (score 1):

Rig Veda [II.1.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02001.htm) says

> tavāghne hotraṃ tava potraṃ ṛtviyaṃ tava neṣṭraṃ tvamaghnid ṛtāyataḥ |
>   tava praśāstraṃ tvamadhvarīyasi **brahmā cāsi** ghṛhapatiśca no dame
>   ||
>
> Thine is the Herald's task and Cleanser's duly timed; Leader art thou,
>   and Kindler for the pious man. Thou art Director, thou the ministering
>   Priest: ***thou art the Brahman***, Lord and Master in our home.

---